# Azure stream analytics output headers case sensitivity?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have query in my job

```
SELECT
 [SomeChar]
,[SomeInt]
INTO [OutCsv]
FROM [InCsv]
```

The output goes to a Azure blob storage. My CSV output displays the column header as

> somechar, someint

But I need,

> SomeChar, SomeInt

Which is what is in input csv as well.

I even tried outputting it to JSON event serialization format but it doesn't preserve the case sensitivity of the field names. I want to preserve the case sensitivity throughout my application. Is there a way in Azure stream analytics to force this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a know limitation currently - ASA will lowercase column names (except SELECT * queries). ASA will be exposing configuration option to preserve case sensitivity in the future.